# How to access all the <form> elements that have been dynamically generated by PHP-MySQL in $_GET upon submitting the form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a simple DB and a small table in it. This table named **STOCK** has only one column - names of different items in a stationery.

I am dynamically generating a form in **PHP-MySQL** which fetches Item from **STOCK** (such as Pencil, Pen etc.) and displays them by using `echo()` function. So I have generated a form which displays Item and correspondingly an `<input>` text box. Upon submitting this form, how can I access all the Names and their text inputs by traversing through the `$_GET` array?

The dynamically generated form is:

```
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock");

        echo "<form name='input' action='add_stock_later.php' method='get'>";
        echo "<table align='left' border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Remarks</>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
          {
            $item = $row['Item'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";

            echo "<td><input type='text' name='$item'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='Remarks'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }

          echo "<tr><td></td>
        <td align='middle'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></td></tr>";


        echo "</table>";
```

Now in the **add_stock_later.php**, how can I access all these `$item` and it's corresponding input without having to manually do it using `$_GET['Pencil'], $_GET['Pen']` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First edit your form.

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$item."[quantity]'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$item."[remarks]'></td>";
```

Then use [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach ($_GET as $stationery => $info) {
    $stationery; // name of the stationery
    $info["quantity"]; // quantity of the stationery
    $info["remarks"]; // remarks for the stationery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so, add to it of course.

```
$required = array('pencil', 'pen', 'paper', 'staples');
foreach ($required as $getKey){
    if (isset($_GET[$getKey]) && $_GET[$getKey] !=''){
        $$getKey = trim($_GET[$getKey]);
    }
}
```

This turns `$_GET['pencil']` into `$pencil` and you don't need to worry about knuckleheads trying to inject garbage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! Anyway I used Antony's solution, as it was more suitable!